order archive page by title in wp twenty twenty-four template
I have been trying to determine how to order the Archive page by Title in the WP Twenty Twenty-Four Template. I cannot find the parameters to do so. Can someone point me to where I can make that change? Thanks.

The pre_get_posts filter can be used to change query parameters (untested):
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_home() ) {
        return;
    }

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
} );


not sure why this is using a static function, but this would change all queries, e.g. date archives, RSS feeds, REST API etc. I'd at least add an is_archive() check

@TomJNowell The $query->is_home() check is not sufficient? I cannot explain the use of static for the anonymous function: all I can point to is that developers more knowledgeable than I have told me to.

static is unnecessary, and I hadn't realised you were checking ! is_home which means it would only impact the homepage and not the archives the user was asking about

I was thinking the OP meant the index page (the use of "THE Archive" instead of "the archives"). is_home() is the blog index, and is_front_page() is the frontpage/homepage.

And yes, static is unnecessary: it will work with and without.
